# Optimize Query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I want to run a query that generates a revenue report for campaigns. There are 2 tables 
members and payments.

```
members (id, campaign_code)
payments (id, member_id, amount)
```

I want to create a table that groups by `campaign_code`, ie in this format

```
campaign_code, member_count, total_revenue
```

I am putting all campaigns into an array and running this,

```
SELECT sum( amount ) AS amt
FROM (members
INNER JOIN payments 
    ON payments.member_id = members.id
)
WHERE campaign_code = 'XX'
```

and it is taking a LOT of time. Anyway to optimize this or do it in a single query?

Comment: Do member_id and id have indexes?

Comment: Yes both have indexes. There would be about 75K members and 80K rows in payments. Not a lot.

Comment: '...where campaign_code in (xx,yy,zz)'. Do the loop to build up a single sql statement that looks like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

payments (id, member_id, amount)
I want to create a table that groups by campaign_code, ie in this format

campaign_code, member_count, total_revenue 
I am putting all campaigns into an array and running this,

```
select
      m.Campaign_Code,
      count( distinct p.member_id) as Members,
      count(*) as PaymentEntries,
      sum( p.amount ) as TotalRevenue
   from
      members m
         join Payments p
            on m.id = p.member_id
   where
      m.campaign_code = 'XX'
```

If you want all campaigns, just remove the WHERE clause.  You mentioned in comments that the tables DO have indexes, but I would ensure that members table has index on campaign_code, and payments has index on member_id.

This query will give a count of distinct members who've contributed, total number of contributions (in case one or more members contributed multiple times), and the totals of all the contributions.

Comment: Thanks Drapp, but this solution gives me an overall picture. I actually wanted data based on campaign codes, i figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you need aggregation for all campaign code, try this

```
SELECT m.campaign_code , count(p.member_id) AS member_count,
  SUM( amount ) AS total_revenue
FROM members m, payments p
WHERE p.member_id = m.id
GROUP BY campaign_code;
```

Make sure to read on mysql group by function

Answer (score 0):

use

```
where campaing_code in ('XX','YY','ZZ','AA','BB')
```

and have an index on campaing_code